# How to Display images from AWS bucket in android app?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to aws s3. I have some images in my aws s3 bucket. How can i retrieve the images and display it in android app.

If anybody knows please tell.

Comment: https://grokonez.com/android/uploaddownload-files-images-amazon-s3-android

Answer (score 1):

Your retrieval URL should look something like below considering that your bucket has no access restrictions.

```
String imagePath = https://s3.YOUR_BUCKET_REGION.amazonaws.com/YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME.jpg
```

For example,

```
String imagePath = https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/my_photos_bucket/my_pic.jpg
```

Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to load the image to your `ImageView`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! .I tried it but i want to display all the images from the bucket. How to achieve it.  When i upload new image in bucket, it should automatically displays in app and all the images should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code similar to below to download a list of files in a bucket

```
AmazonS3Client s3 = create you AmazonS3Client

ObjectListing listing = s3.listObjects( bucketName, prefix );
List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = listing.getObjectSummaries();

while (listing.isTruncated()) {
   listing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects (listing);
   summaries.addAll (listing.getObjectSummaries());
}

for(S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : summaries) {
    String key = objectSummary.getKey(); 
    //download the file with object key = key 
}
```